# How to get youtube thumbnails in a listview using JSON in Android? My code so far:

Tags: android

Trying yo get info on how to use all the tags in the url mentioned in the code below.

public class YoutubeVideoMain extends Activity {

```
ListView videolist;

ArrayList<String> videoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> videoadapter;
Context context;

String feedURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/twistedequations/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=5";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.youtubelist);
    videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videolist);

    videoadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.video_list_item,
            videoArrayList);

    videolist.setAdapter(videoadapter);
    VideoListTask loadertask = new VideoListTask();
    loadertask.execute();
}

private class VideoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialogue;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialogue.dismiss();

        videoadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialogue = new ProgressDialog(context);

        dialogue.setTitle("Loading items..");
        dialogue.show();
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedURL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
            int statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();

            if (statuscode != 200) {

                return null;
            }

            InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                builder.append(line);

            }
            String jsonData = builder.toString();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray items = data.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject video = items.getJSONObject(i);

                videoArrayList.add(video.getString("title"));

            }

            Log.i("YouJsonData:", jsonData);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I am trying to get thumbnails in the listview and also trying to open a new video player on click of any item. The above code is displaying list of items with a title of the video but I also want to add thumbnails to it.

Help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Universal ImageL0ader for Lazy Loading. You download the same and use it or use a different technique. Customize the below according to your needs.

1. Use a `thread` or `Asynctask` to make a http request to the json response.
2. Parse the response and store it in a list.
3. Use a Custom Adapter to display the data.

You can also use Volley library.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> thumb = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading..");
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TheTask().execute();
            }

       });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void getData()
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/twistedequations/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=5");

        try
        {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title1 = jsonObject.getString("title");
            title.add(title1);
            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
            URL url1 = new URL(thumbUrl);
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
            thumb.add(thumbUrl);
            String url;
            try {

                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
                msg.add(url);
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            }
        }
        } 
        catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        YouTubeAdapter you = new YouTubeAdapter(MainActivity.this,msg,title,thumb);
        lv.setAdapter(you);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getData();
        return null;
    }

  }
}

public class YouTubeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mContext;
    Intent intent;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<String> mVideo;
    ArrayList<String> mTitle;
    ArrayList<String> mThumb;
    static DisplayImageOptions options;
    static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public YouTubeAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> a,ArrayList<String> title,ArrayList<String> thumb)  {
        mContext=context;
        mVideo=a;   
        mTitle = title;
        mThumb= thumb;
         options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .resetViewBeforeLoading()
         .cacheOnDisc()
         .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
         .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
         .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
         .build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mVideo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder vh;

        if(arg1==null)
        {
            arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
            vh= new ViewHolder();
            vh.tv1=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            vh.tv2=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            vh.iv=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            vh.pb = (ProgressBar) arg1.findViewById(R.id.pb);
            arg1.setTag(vh);
        }
        else
        {
            vh= (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        }
        vh.tv1.setText(mTitle.get(position));
        vh.tv2.setText(mVideo.get(position));
        display(vh.iv, mThumb.get(position), vh.pb); 
        return arg1;
    }

    static  public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
    {
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

    });
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        ImageView iv;
        ProgressBar pb;
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It did gave me an idea. So, basically we can also make a new image adapter and store the images with its position and then populate the list view with the content already present there. But For that, we also need to make changes in the layout cause we also need an Image View so that we can change the image later in the adapter after getting the thumbnail.

Comment: @mike20132013 i din't understand your comment. why do you need to change the image in the adapter and what is that you want exactly.

Comment: But what do u think about launching a custom video player instead of youtube player on click of any item?

Comment: @mike20132013 you need to have a video view with media player controller and use the url to stream video. that's entirely a different question to the one posted here. fro your question posted here i have answered and it works.

Comment: Ya..i think it makes sense now. Thanks a lot for your help..:)